# c++ - Efficient algorithm to search for matching substrings

Tags: c++, algorithm, full-text-search, suffix-tree

Example: I have many patterns like this:

```
sexy hello
sex every
sex example
...
```

I have a query like this:

```
hello, sexygirl.
```

This query will match the first pattern. Because it contains sexy and hello. 
Attention: sexy and girl have no blank.

Is there any efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: What query?  I see no code.